# VBA: Return more than 2 filter criterias

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I am having a standard filter on a bunch of columns and i want to read the filter criterias. This wasn't really a problem until the case where more than 2 criteria are selected. I have a row with different strings and i want do be able to get the criteria the user has chosen. Currently I am working with this piece of code:

```
Set ws = Worksheets(actSheet)
For Each flt In ws.AutoFilter.Filters
    If flt.On = True Then
        criterias = criterias & flt.Criteria1 & ", "
        criterias = criterias & flt.Criteria2 & ", "
    End If
Next flt
```

This only gives me the opportunity to get 2 Criteria max. 
I have found this line of code in different forums, but it was used for other reasons and i do not really know how to use this code for me:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(param1, param2, param3,...) _
                       Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

This way you can *set* criteria i think, but i want to *get* it.
Any ideas how i can use this code? Or another suggestion for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:

Well i've worked a lot of hours on this and still no Solution. It is not really possible to get the Array in Criteria1 in an Array. Always the same Error "Can not assign to array". Although i assigned the same array to the Filter Criteria1 10 lines of code before...

So this works:

```
Dim arr(3) As String
arr(2) = "test1"
arr(1) = "test2"
arr(3) = "test3"

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But this doesn't:

```
arr = ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Criteria1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit2:** This gets the filters and it's headers

```
Sub GetFilteredItems()
    Dim fl As Filter
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    Dim myfilters As String

    For Each fl In ws.AutoFilter.Filters
        If fl.On Then
            If Len(myfilters) = 0 Then
                myfilters = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(0, i).Resize(1, 1).Value
            Else
                myfilters = myfilters & "; " & _
                    ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(0, i).Resize(1, 1).Value
            End If
            If fl.Count > 2 Then
                myfilters = myfilters & ": " & Replace(Join(fl.Criteria1), "=", "")
            Else
                myfilters = myfilters & ": " & Replace(fl.Criteria1, "=", "")
                On Error Resume Next
                myfilters = myfilters & " " & Replace(fl.Criteria2, "=", "")
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Debug.Print myfilters
End Sub
```

I remove other codes to avoid confusing the reader.
This is much like the OP's approach but a little bit direct. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But i had such an approach earlier and it has one Problem, i'll explain it by example: Col1 contains Test1, Test2 and Test3; Col2 contains 1,2,1. Now i filter Col1 by Test1 and Test2, and Col2 by 1. 
At this point the method returns only Test1 and 1, but it should return Test1, Test2 and 1.

What i do not understand, if i point the mouse ofer the filter-dropdown button, it says exactly what i want to get! But i don't know where to get it... And since i didn't find an answer in over a weeks research, i might think that there is no answer.

Comment: @sk1ll Actually that routine can get the filters on other columns as well. But you need to add the check if something is filtered.

Comment: i know but the method runs when all the filters are set. And only looks at the values after all filters are applied. In a situation like i stated above, it could be that there is a filter set, but there is no actual value because an other filter in another column is making the row invisible.
Was that understandable? Or do i just miss something and don't understand you?

Comment: @sk1ll Yes I understand. Again you need to get the range with filters before you apply the function. See my additional sub to get the ranges with active filters.

Comment: i really seem to don't get it..
The Function GetFilters is looking for unique items, so every cellvalue which appears is stored in it and then this is the Filtercriteria.
But if a cell is not visible anymore because of another filtered column, it does not appear in the Criteria List, but it should. 
I think we talk past each other, or I'm just a bit dizzy :p

Comment: @sk1ll Ah, I get it now. The other filters will not be returned once it's over written by the other filters. :) Sorry my bad. But I'll leave my answer here just in case someone found a use of it. I'll update as soon as I found something up to help you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I highly appreciate that after working on this for a week now! 
See my answer to my question for a solution, i got it on another board.

Comment: @sk1ll yeah while driving home, I thought the answer to your problem is in front of us the whole time. :) the Filter Object Criteria1 property returns what you want, you just need to check what the criteria is. :)

Comment: @sk1ll btw, I also posted my solution :D.

Comment: The main problem was that i didn't know what it returnes, i don't know, after all the solution seems quite simple :p Thank you for your solution for the headers! My version was not 100% correct...not even 50 :p
Your code looks a bit nicer, i ticked it as best answer ;) 
And thanks for the upvote, finally i can comment on other peoples problems^^

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found an answer!

The issue was not too big, just really hard to get an answer on this because you nearly don't find anything on the internet.

```
Dim criterias As String
Dim arr As Variant

For Each flt In ws.AutoFilter.Filters
If flt.On = True Then
    'write the column head in the string
    criterias = criterias & "=" & _ 
    ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(0, i - 1).Resize(1, 1).Value & ": "
    If flt.Count > 2 Then
        arr = flt.Criteria1                   '<----- my problem
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)    '<-----
            criterias = criterias & arr(i)    '<-----
        Next                                  '<-----
    Else
        criterias = criterias & flt.Criteria1
        On Error Resume Next
        criterias = criterias & flt.Criteria2 & ", "
    End If

End If
i = i + 1
Next flt
```

ws is just my active Worksheet

I didn't realise that i should make the array Variant, and not initialise it as a simple String array.

After that the criterias String looks like "Criteria1: =test1=test2=test3", so just replace the "=" with ", " or something like that and you're done!

Axel Richter from a german office board was a big help in this issue ;) (for the german readers: http://www.office-loesung.de/p/viewtopic.php?f=166&t=666472&p=2773974#p2773974)